# ToolStrip covering controls

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5, tabcontrol, toolstrip

My `ToolStrip` covers my `TabControl`. I have played with the docking and anchoring but cannot figure out how to stop this.

My `TabControl` has `Dock` set to `Fill`.

Whatever my `ToolStrip` has `Dock` set to, it still covers the `TabControl`

[image: ToolStrip covering TabControl]

Comment: Right mouse click the ToolStrip and try selecting `BringToFront`.

Comment: @LarsTech Just tried. Sorry, it didn't work

Comment: Oops.  Meant `SendToBack`.  Alternatively, go to "View - Other Windows - Document Outline" to play with the control placements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use a `ToolStripContainer` control, and then put the `TabControl` within the `ContentPanel` of the `ToolStripContainer` and the `ToolStrip` in the `TopToolStripPanel` of the `ToolStripContainer`.

As a note, once the `ToolStrip` was in the `TopToolStripPanel`, I had to use the keyboard keys to move its position left and right as using the mouse kept placing the `ToolStrip` out of the `TopToolStripPanel`.

Also, using the `View - Other Windows - Document Outline` as LarsTech suggested was a HUGE help is placing the `ToolStrip` and `TabControl` within the `ToolStripContainer`

Answer (score 4):

1. TabControl has Dock set to Fill.
2. ToolStrip has Dock set to Left.
3. Right mouse click the ToolStrip and try selecting Send to Back.